# cMessage tag disappears when message leaves compound module

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Consider this: I have a switch (the gray square) which is a compound module. Inside of this switch there again are more compound modules. Basically there are 3 layers of compound modules and inside the green rounded squares there are simple modules.

[image]

My Problem appears inside the green rounded modules. I create a Tag and assign it to each frame that arrives at the first green module. Then some other processing steps are done (based on the information contained in the tag) by other simple modules inside this first green module. Now, when leaving the first green compound module and entering the second (red arrow), somehow my tag is lost and all its information with it.

I add the tag in the first green module like this:

```
void filterPrep::handleMessage(cMessage* msg){
     if(msg->isSelfMsg()){

     }
     else{
         inet::Packet* packet = check_and_cast<inet::Packet*>(msg);
         FilterTag* tag; 
         tag = packet->addTag<FilterTag>();
         tag->setValue1(someValue); //This works fine
     }
     send(msg, "out");
}
```

I read the tag in every simple module in the first green module like this. That works fine but in the second green module (e.g. the next compound module) this yields a `nullptr`

```
void filtering::handleMessage(cMessage* msg){
    if(msg->isSelfMsg()){
    
    }
    else{
        inet::Packet* packet = check_and_cast<inet::Packet*>(msg);
        FilterTag* fetchedTag;
        fetchedTag = packet->getTag<FilterTag>(); // throws exception 
        fetchedTag->getValue1();
   }
}
```

I have no Idea why this could be happening, can you help me out?

Comment: It is not clear what happens. First you say something returns a 'nullptr' and then a line is also annotated in the source that it throws an exception? Now which one is happening?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is that this is really legitimate. The code you use to get  tag value assumes that **each and every** message is actually a `Packet` and  each one has a `FilterTag` associated with it. As the first green module is a compound one, there might be cases when somehow a packet travels on a route where a `FilterTag` is not added. This may or may not be true. hard to tell from the information above. So in short, make sure that the packet which generates the exception was actually augmented with a tag in the first place. The tag is not removed, but rather it was never added in the first place. You should debug this behavior because your assumptions (that each packet has a tag) may not be true.